# Blazor Interopt Js in separate project doesn't refresh, even by removing cache, bin/obj

Tags: caching, import, blazor, interop

This is a cache issue I guess. Let me explain,

I have a .net6 blazor project (client server and shared project) which as a referenced project call ReactorBlazorMapbox (Razor library), which is in charge with JsInterop to play with mapbox js.

Code in progress, but works great yet. Display a map, display popup...

The ReactorBlazorMapbox project has its own JS file, called MapboxInterop.js. This file is loaded in ./_content/ReactorBlazorMapbox/MapboxInterop.js
This way, no need to reference the file in the client projet. It's embeded. Great.

My problem is, when I modify this file, nothing happend. Clear cache CTRL-F5, manualy clearing cache using inpector/Application/Cache/Delete (or local/session storage). I also removed bin/obj, clean solution, re generate projects on C# side.

My MapboxInterop.js in the browser does not refresh. (using inspector/Source)

I had to rename it MapboxInterop2.js and change my link in the import, this way it works. At least one time. But add a new file each time modification is done in this file will be time killer...

I found a work around, instead of using a embeded js interopt file from the side project, I put this one in the Blazor Client /wwwwroot/js path and add this line :

```
//load js from client projet path
_Module = await _JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./js/MapboxInterop.js");

instead of 
//load js from this project
_Module = await _JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./_content/ReactorBlazorMapbox/MapboxInterop2.js");
```

this way, when re running the site with VS2022, the file in cache is refreshed.

If someone has an idea so the same thing happen for a embed project js...

Answer (score 1):

FCK me :)

I forgot to check "disable cache" checkbox in the browser inspector.

But, there is a cache difference between those two files. (client vs project)...